# Closing files in CPython

Tags: python

If in CPython when the reference counter drops to zero the object space is *immediately* reclaimed how much   is closing a file important? I mean if `f` is a file object and I do `f = 10` then the file object space will automatically reclaimed and close will be called.

Comment: When a file is closed, the internal write buffer is flushed. If you don't implicitly flush the buffer by closing the file, you can run into a race condition when reading and writing from the same file. In general it's better not to rely on CPython implementation details. I often switch between CPython and PyPy, so it's better to just stick to what all Python implementations implement.

Comment: You can't assume that an object is garbage-collected immediately after its reference count reaches 0.

Comment: @chepner In Cpython it does so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although CPython can handle object memory reclaiming based on the reference count, it is a good practice to free external resources like files as soon as they are not needed anymore.

Extracted from https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

"""
When you’re done with a file, call f.close() to close it and free up any system resources taken up by the open file. After calling f.close(), attempts to use the file object will automatically fail.

```
>>>
>>> f.close()
>>> f.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks:

```
>>>
>>> with open('workfile', 'r') as f:
...     read_data = f.read()
>>> f.closed
True
```

"""